# Snakemake rebuild/reschedule of jobs

Tags: python, bioinformatics, jobs, job-scheduling, snakemake

I am writing a pipeline in Snakemake for people that don't have much programming knowledge, so I want to want them to be able to run the entire pipeline by only requesting `snakemake all -c` in the command line.

I have 2 config files in my Snakefile:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
configfile: "config_samples.yaml"
```

These config files will be merged together by Snakemake.

`config.yaml` is the standard config file. `config_samples.yaml` is a config file of which its contents change depending on the pipeline input. It looks like the following:

```
samples:
  CYP20130000B:
    R1: CYP20130000B_R1.fastq
    R2: CYP20130000B_R2.fastq
  SAT20020000A:
    R1: SAT20020000A_R1.fastq
    R2: SAT20020000A_R2.fastq
  ...
```

I am using a Python script in a Snakemake rule to generate the contents of `config_samples.yaml` (using the snakemake script directive). This works fine.

However, when I list all my wanted output in the `all` rule like so:

```
"config_samples.done", # flag file for rule that generates config_samples.yaml
expand(QC_raw_reads/{sample}_{direction}_fastqc.html", sample=config["samples"], direction=["R1", "R2"])
```

Then this won't work, because the `expand()` will only expand to samples that are in the *current* `config_samples.yaml`, so before the Python script actually generates the new `config_samples.yaml` with the new samples.

This can easily be avoided by running the rule that generates `config_samples.yaml` separately before running the enterire pipeline, but to refer back to the beginning, I want it to stay as easy as possible for non-programmers.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to let Snakemake rebuild/reschedule the jobs, so that they can be updated for the new samples.

Comment: You are putting the card before the horse. Why do you need that is yaml file? You generate this config, then you plan to read this config for the next run... Why not to work with the contents of this config even without creating a yaml file?

Comment: No, I want to generate the config, for _that_ same run. For example, if I do a first run with 3 samples, then the yaml will be generated with 3 samples, and it will work fine. However, if I then want to run again but with new samples, lets say 5, then this won't work, because then when I request the `all` rule in the command line, the output files are expanded with the previous 3 samples because those will still be in the yaml, and not the 5 new ones because these haven't been generated yet by the rule that does that.

Comment: So why do you even need the yaml? The config shall be the source of information, but in your case something else is the source.

Comment: Because in the config I have the information for all the tools and what not, and in this other yaml I want to list the samples because this can get a very long list, and I want to keep that separate from the config file (and besides that, writing the samples to the yaml is easier because I can just completely overwrite it and don't have to worry about deleting something from the config)

Comment: You don't need to keep te list of samples in the config file at all.

Comment: I feel like I do? Because I request output while using wildcards and `expand()` like so: `expand(dir/{sample}.txt, sample=config["samples"])`

Comment: Is that cut in stone? Checkpoints is probably what you need.

Comment: Nothing stops you from calling a Python function from within your Snakefile, as the very first thing, creating a global dictionary that holds exactly what you want `config["samples"]` to contain. As Dmitry says, you seem to have a limited understanding of Snakemake capabilities and thus seem to think it has to be done your one way - but that's just not the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire problem seems to come about because of this sentence:

> I am using a Python script in a Snakemake rule to generate the contents of config_samples.yaml (using the snakemake script directive). This works fine.

The solution could be as simple as realising that the Python script could run *outside of a Snakemake rule* just at the beginning of your Snakefile. A Snakefile is basically a Python script. So you can just import your script into that Snakefile and execute it there.

So your Snakefile could look like this:

```py
import config_generator
config = config_generator.add_samples(config)

rule all:
   input: expand(QC_raw_reads/{sample}_{direction}_fastqc.html", sample=config["samples"], direction=["R1", "R2"])

rule A:
...
```

`config_generator.py` would look like this:

```py
def add_samples(config):
    # here you can calculate whatever you calculate to get config_samples
    # e.g. config["samples"] = ...
    return config
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I wasn't sure at first if it would because I do use `config.yaml` to retrieve the full path to the samples, but as long as you put `config = config_generator.add_samples(config)` **after** `configfile: config.yaml` in `snakefile`, this works.

Comment: Update: this doesn't seem to work too well if you use the `run` directive for a rule. This rule then has access to anything defined in the Snakefile, also outside of the rule, and it seems like it then constantly reruns `config_generator.add_samples(config)`, but I'm not 100% sure (the errors I get are very inconsistent and probably specific for my case)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully digested the questions and the comments underneath, but I feel agreeing with @DmitryKuzminov in that the current setup is a bit contrieved.

In any case, I think you can make snakemake to regenerate `config_samples.yaml` by adding towards the top of the Snakefile, before the first rule, something like:

```
if os.path.exists('config_samples.yaml'):
    os.remove('config_samples.yaml')
```

you could even make that step controllable on the command line with:

```
if config['remake_config'] == 'yes':
    if os.path.exists('config_samples.yaml'):
        os.remove('config_samples.yaml')
```

and then execute with:

```
snakemake -C remake_config='yes' ...
```

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, but not exactly what I'm looking for. By the time I request my wanted output in the command line, the config file has already been read by Snakemake, but then `config_samples.yaml` still contains the old samples, instead of the new ones that will be generated during the run. I was looking for a way to let Snakemake update its config dict with the newly generated samples during the run, so that the appropriate output for every new sample can be generated. However, I feel right now that this is just not possible, so I'll just let the user run two commands to fix this